# Can the Sony A7 II custom user modes be configured to not display on the EVF when selected?

Tags: sony, camera-settings, mirrorless, sony-a7ii

When I switch the mode dial to a custom user mode (1 or 2), the whole user mode parameters will show up on the monitor/EVF, can I opt not to see that? It's kinda annoying when you want to switch & shoot. Now, I have to switch and see the parameters on the screen and then half-press the shutter button to dismiss it and shoot.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you just press display a couple of times. I work in a camera shop and can try this and confirm tomorrow (gmt) will edit my answer to either confirm this or give the correct answer

Comment: So glad I could help. If possible and you have the rep please upvote my answer so I can build my own rep as I am new and also others in the same situation can see my answer was accepted.

Comment: not a problem! just did ;D

Comment: I'm still waiting for your result, did you forget me?

Comment: Very sorry for the delay, I've just had chance to look at one, go through the menus etc, and all I can find to change the display is the disp option. The only other thing that I thought might help is to have the screen display the parameters and when you put your eye to the viewfinder this will automatically disapear. I hope this helps with your issue.

Comment: @Vik - Begging for upvotes isn't nice, rather pathetic. If you care about rep the best way to get that is to be often on the site, read a lot of questions, and provide answers when you think you can add something useful. Since you work in a camera shop you should be able to help people with the use of their camera.